# how an utility application connects with all three deployment types of CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am working with an utility application which has user authentication(i.e. it takes username password from users as input). Previously I worked with `CRM online`. Now requirement is this utility should be able to connect all three deployment types of CRM (i.e. Onpremise, Online, IFD).I am not sure how to do it. I was using `crmservice.cs` and `deviceidmanager.cs` for connection with CRM.

From other online resources I found that in connection string if I add `Authentication Type="Integrated"/"AD"/"SPLA"/"Passport"` , it should work.

So If I write my connection string like

`connectionString="Authentication Type="Integrated";Data Source= LINE500\sage;Initial Catalog=cs3live; Integrated Security=false; User Id=XXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX"`

Is this gonna work? FYI, I have only CRM online trial account to verify my code.So I need your help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

a CRM Online environment can use Windows Live ID or Office 365 authentication, `DeviceID` and `DevicePassword` are necessary only when connecting with Windows Live ID credentials. So you need to know which authentication type is in use in your CRM.

To be able to connect to different environments I suggest to use the Simplified Connection, you can find more information here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930366/2191473

and here:

[Sample: Simplified Connection Quick Start using Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602970.aspx)