# Copying data from Linq to CRM

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to work with some data in the Dynamics Online of my client. They have some custom elements added by a third party company who aren't being at all helpful.

I need to get contacts from the standard contactSet and then grab their data from the membershipSet created by this third party org.

I'm really struggling with how to go about getting the data out of the CRM and onto the website.

```
from m in py3_membershipSet
join c in ContactSet on m.py3_Member.Id equals c.ContactId 
where m.statuscode.Value == 1
orderby m.py3_name
select m
```

This has led me to try the following on my .Net site:

```
var context = new XrmServiceContext();
var activeMembers = (from m in context.py3_membershipSet
join c in context.ContactSet on m.py3_Member.Id equals c.ContactId 
where m.statuscode.Value == 1
orderby m.py3_name
select m)
```

However, 'context' doesn't seem to contain py3_membershipSet.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to generate the early bound classes (using crmsvcutil.exe) and specify the `ServiceContextName` parameter.

Assuming your context is `XrmServiceContext`, you need to instantiate in this way:

```cs
var context = new XrmServiceContext(service);
```

where `service` is the `IOrganizationService` web service.

Comment: Whate is the IOraganisationService and where will I find it? Thanks.

Comment: check this link [http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/sample-code-for-using-iorganizationservice-in-crm-2011/](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/sample-code-for-using-iorganizationservice-in-crm-2011/) and this link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309449.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309449.aspx)

Comment: because you are using CRM Online, check also this connection example: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929879/ms-dynamics-crm-online-2011-authentication-issues/15930366#15930366](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929879/ms-dynamics-crm-online-2011-authentication-issues/15930366#15930366)

Comment: Thanks Guido, maybe its because Ive been staring at this all day...but I dont see the connection between your links and my apparent need to run crmsutil.

Comment: ah ok. I see thats how to build the IOrganisationService. Thanks. Can the ServiceContextName be any name that isnt already in use? Or is it something more specific?

Comment: You need to run the crmsvcutil to generate the classes (and the context too), for the name there isn't a fixed rule, you can choose for example something like CompanyNameContext, because normally the generated context is used only with the specific crm organization.

Comment: Im using a package that apparently comes with var context = new XrmServiceContext(); working for a set of entities. Presumably its best for me to reuse this name so that existing references dont break. Presumably this will also add my additional bits into the mix. rather than breaking those which exist in XrmServiceContext()