# Error when trying to receive Information from CRM 2011 Webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm receiving an error while trying to retrieve systemuser information from Dynamics CRM 2011.  The following Code works:

```
public List<CrmUser> GetAllCrmUsers()
{
    List<CrmUser> CrmUsers = new List<CrmUser>();
    using (CrmSdk.OrganizationServiceClient myCrm = new CrmSdk.OrganizationServiceClient("CustomBinding_IOrganizationService1"))
    {
        try
        {

            // this will need to be changed... the address to a key in the app.config and the credentials will need to be whatever is correct for the
            // end server to hit the CRM WCF service
            myCrm.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://devcrm.removed/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
            myCrm.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;


            CrmSdk.ColumnSet colsPrincipal = new CrmSdk.ColumnSet();

            colsPrincipal.Columns = new string[] { "lastname", "firstname", "domainname", "systemuserid" };

            CrmSdk.QueryExpression queryPrincipal = new CrmSdk.QueryExpression();
            queryPrincipal.EntityName = "systemuser";
            queryPrincipal.ColumnSet = colsPrincipal;

            CrmSdk.EntityCollection myAccounts = myCrm.RetrieveMultiple(queryPrincipal);

            foreach (CrmSdk.Entity myEntity in myAccounts.Entities)
            {
                //create new crm users and add it to the list
                CrmUser thisOne = new CrmUser();

                thisOne.firstName = myEntity.Attributes[0].Value.ToString();
                thisOne.lastName = myEntity.Attributes[1].Value.ToString();
                thisOne.userId = myEntity.Attributes[2].Value.ToString();
                thisOne.userGuid = myEntity.Attributes[3].Value.ToString();

                CrmUsers.Add(thisOne);

            }


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CrmUser thisOne = new CrmUser();
            thisOne.firstName = "Crap there was an error";
            thisOne.lastName = ex.ToString();
            CrmUsers.Add(thisOne);
        }
    }
    return CrmUsers;
}
```

However if I try to add "businessunitid" to the ColumnSet when I invoke the service I get an error stating:

> "Error in line 1 position 1879. Element \ 2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value\' contains data from a type that maps to the name \'/xrm/2011/Contracts:OptionSetValue\'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to \'OptionSetValue\' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.\'"

This error is because the data being returned is the type "Lookup" according to the [metadata information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328525.aspx). I tried adding `[KnownType(typeof(OptionSetValue))]` just under the `[Data Contract]` tag to no avail and I've been Googling and Binging(?) this for two days now so if it's already been answered I apologize.

Comment: curiosity: which CRM assemblies you are using in your code? are from crm 2011 sdk? CrmUser is a custom class?

Comment: Yes, CrmUser is a custom class, containing 4 strings. firstName,lastName,userId,userGuid.  I'm using the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk assembly Version 5.0.0.0.

Comment: can you please specify the type of your application (silverlight, windows forms, web service) and if silverlight if running as webresource inside crm or not

Comment: probably just need to add [KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(EntityReference))] but I'm curious to know why you are using this kind of connection to CRM

Comment: I believe your error is being caused by CRM returning an OptionSetValue, and the code attempting to deserialize it on the client side doesn't have a reference to the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, but you've mentioned that it does, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: I'm creating a WCF service that connects to our CRM Web service. When I invoke the getAllCrmUsers() on the WCF test client I get the error if I include any data field that is not listed as a 'primitive?' datatype.  I can retrieve strings, doubles, integers ect however the datatypes identified as 'Picklist' or 'Lookup' cause this error.  The first project we are going to use our custom web service for is to compare active users in another database and see if there is a corresponding user for CRM and if not create one.

Comment: suggestion: instead to add the crm endpoint as service reference inside your project (probably you saw this method inside the book Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Unleashed) just use IOrganizationService or OrganizationService (check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929879/ms-dynamics-crm-online-2011-authentication-issues) will be more easy to manage all the types

Comment: Thank you I like that way of connecting and I'm defintely going to study the article you linked in it.  I am using the IOrganizationService to connect to the CRM webservice.  That's how I'm retrieving data.  It just seems I can't retrieve the business unit GUID or the security role GUID that I need to move forward on my project.  Thank you for linking that other article though it will be of some help on the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it.  You have to open the auto generated Reference.cs code.  Do a search for the entity class:

```
public partial class Entity : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

Go to the line above it and add the known type stuff so the entity can de-serialize it.

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(EntityReference))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(OptionSetValue))]
public partial class Entity : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

Comment: I also discovered that you also have to back in and re-add it any time you update or change the service reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just leverage `Microsoft.Xrm.Client`. It provides you with `CrmConnection`, a simplified way to connect to the system.

I also suggest (but it's probably more a matter of taste/needs) to always read attributes through `GetAttributeValue<>` for more readable code.

Full working sample including BU id:

```
// helper class
public static class CommonCrm
{        
    public static readonly CrmConnection crmConnection = null;
    public static readonly OrganizationService crmService = null;
    public static readonly CrmOrganizationServiceContext crmContext = null;

    static CommonCrm()
    {
        try
        {
            CommonCrm.crmConnection = new CrmConnection("Crm");

// "Crm" is a connection string which goes like this in Web.config:
//<connectionStrings>
//    <add name="Crm" connectionString="Url=http://orgUrl; Domain=X; Username=Y; Password=Z;" />
//</connectionStrings>

            CommonCrm.crmService = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);
            CommonCrm.crmContext = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(crmService);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception (code removed)
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class CrmUser
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public Guid userGuid { get; set; }
    public Guid buId { get; set; }

    public static List<CrmUser> GetAllCrmUsers()
    {
        List<CrmUser> CrmUsers = new List<CrmUser>();
        try
        {
            ColumnSet colsPrincipal = new ColumnSet("lastname", "firstname", "domainname", "systemuserid", "businessunitid");
            QueryExpression queryPrincipal = new QueryExpression();
            queryPrincipal.EntityName = "systemuser";
            queryPrincipal.ColumnSet = colsPrincipal;

            var myAccounts = CommonCrm.crmContext.RetrieveMultiple(queryPrincipal);

            foreach (var myEntity in myAccounts.Entities)
            {
                //create new crm users and add it to the list
                CrmUser thisOne = new CrmUser();

                thisOne.firstName = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("firstname");
                thisOne.lastName = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
                thisOne.userId = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("domainname");
                thisOne.userGuid = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("systemuserid");
                thisOne.buId = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("businessunitid").Id;
                // and so on and so forth...         

                CrmUsers.Add(thisOne);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CrmUser thisOne = new CrmUser();
            thisOne.firstName = "Crap there was an error";
            thisOne.lastName = ex.ToString();
            CrmUsers.Add(thisOne);
        }

        return CrmUsers;
    }
}
```

Comment: They are working on reloading the dev CRM server and it has been down so I haven't had a chance to try your suggestion.  Thanks for the input though I'll be sure to post more once it's back up.