# IFD/ADFS connection errors in WCF service to CRM 2011

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011, adfs

I'm currently trying to figure out why this is failing.

Here is how I'm building the objects to connect the organization webservice in a go between WCF service.  The deployment is IFD/ADFS

```
    string uname = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uname"];
    string password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
    //string domain = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"];

    //Construct connection objects
    Uri _organizationUri = new Uri(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"]);
    Uri _homeRealmUri = null;
    ClientCredentials _credentials = new ClientCredentials();

    OrganizationServiceProxy _orgProxy; 
    IOrganizationService _service;

    IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> config;

    //Initialize connection objects
    public void init()
    {
        _credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(uname, password);

        config = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(_organizationUri);

        _orgProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(config, _credentials);
        //_orgProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(_organizationUri, _homeRealmUri, _credentials, null);
        _service = (IOrganizationService)_orgProxy;

    }
```

Trying to do retrieve (or any other functionality via _service)

```
LeadEntity = _service.Retrieve("lead", leadID, new ColumnSet(true));
```

gets me an error that says "The logon attempt failed!"

Then I did some googling and found someone suggested putting in the domain like this uname@domain.  That changes the error to:

SOAP security negotiation with 'https://adfstst.xyxy.com/adfs/services/trust/13/kerberosmixed'    for target 'https://adfstst.xyxy.com/adfs/services/trust/13/kerberosmixed' failed. See inner exception for more details

The inner exception says this:

InitializeSecurityContent failed. Ensure the service principal name is correct.

Any advice on how to fix the connection would be appreciated.

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930366/2191473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use following code:

```
public void init()
{
    _credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    _credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
    _credentials.UserName.UserName = uname;
    _credentials.UserName.Password = password;

    IOrganizationService service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(_organizationUri), null, credentials, null);
}
```

Comment: These two lines of code don't seem to contribute anything in the above example:
_credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    _credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;