# Connect To Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Online From Windows Azure Hosted Website

Tags: asp.net, azure, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have hosted a asp.net website on Windows Azure and trying to connect to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Online. But I am getting below error:

The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

> Error Source =    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData,
>   Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceUserName.Encrypt(String value) in
>   c:\DWASFiles\sites\mfs\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Code\DeviceidManager.cs:line
>   869    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceUserName.UpdateCredentials(String
>   encryptedValue, String decryptedValue) in
>   c:\DWASFiles\sites\mfs\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Code\DeviceidManager.cs:line
>   840    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceUserName.set_DecryptedPassword(String
>   value) in
>   c:\DWASFiles\sites\mfs\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Code\DeviceidManager.cs:line
>   796    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.GenerateDeviceUserName()
>   in
>   c:\DWASFiles\sites\mfs\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Code\DeviceidManager.cs:line
>   390    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.RegisterDevice(Guid
>   applicationId, Uri issuerUri, String deviceName, String
>   devicePassword) in
>   c:\DWASFiles\sites\mfs\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Code\DeviceidManager.cs:line
>   185    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice(Uri
>   issuerUri, String deviceName, String devicePassword) in
>   c:\DWASFiles\sites\mfs\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Code\DeviceidManager.cs:line
>   109    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice(Uri
>   issuerUri) in
>   c:\DWASFiles\sites\mfs\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Code\DeviceidManager.cs:line
>   92    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice()
>   in
>   c:\DWASFiles\sites\mfs\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Code\DeviceidManager.cs:line
>   70    at ServerConnection.ConnectToCRM() in
>   c:\DWASFiles\sites\mfs\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Code\CrmService.cs:line
>   56

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks Chandrabhanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your log looks like that you are connecting against a CRM Online instance that is still using `Windows Live Id` authentication, the `DeviceidManager.cs` is a big clue but not a complete proof.
`Windows Live Id` authentication still needs the device credentials, this is an issue on Azure hosted apps.

Try to use the simplified connection, you can find an example here:

[MS Dynamics CRM online 2011 - Authentication issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929879/ms-dynamics-crm-online-2011-authentication-issues)

Comment: Yes. You are right. DeviceidManager.cs was causing the problem. I used simple codes                                                   string CrmConnection crmConnection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=" + crmserver + "; Username=" + username + "; Password=" + password + ";");

OrganizationService serviceProxy = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);