# Adding value to LOOKUP field in microsoft dynamics crm 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to update a look up field in account using xrm services of microsoft dynamics crm 2011.

Need some ideas.Pls. Help

Answer (score 2):

Lookup fields in CRM 2011 are `EntityReference`, this means you need to know the `LogicalName` of the entity the lookup is pointing and the `Id` of the record.

Assuming you are already connected to CRM (you can use simplified connection as this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930366/2191473)

you can set the lookup field using this syntax:

```
Entity recordToUpdate = service.Retrieve("contact", contactId, new ColumnSet(true));
recordToUpdate["parentcustomerid"] = new EntityReference("account", accountId);
service.Update(recordToUpdate);
```

you first get the record tu update, after set the lookup field with an EntityReference and after you save the record.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download the [Developer Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372957.aspx) for CRM 2011.

2) Follow the directions to develop and deploy a plugin solution

The toolkit contains templates for plugins similar to the one you require.  Guido's answer for the actual lookup modification is correct.