# Can I run the CRM sdk to my Dynamics CRM test account?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I created a test account for microsoft Dynamics, which resulted in a xyz.crm4.dynamics.com address.

Now I have troubles running the SDK examples, which give me a authentication issue.

So I wondered: is it even possible to run the SDK examples to a testaccount?

===================

What I did:
I start the example, and on the command prompt I was asked for the crm server (i entered xyz.crm4.dynamics.com)

and i was asked if it runs in office 365 (i entered no).

Then I got an error there is nog dev.xyz.crm4.dynamics.com service (I removed the dev. part from the example code, is that ok?)

then I had to enter my windows live id account, which i did, and the I got an error on this line: `discoveryProxy.Execute(new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest());`

Comment: Check the service endpoint address under *Settings > Customization > Developer Resources* ... if I recall it right the address includes `api`: xyz.api.crm4.dynamics.com.

Comment: And which credentials should I use? Is it the michel@xyz.onmicrosoft.com which received? And should I type crm4.dynamics.com or xyz.crm4.dynamics.com as domain in the first step?

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the Developer Resources at first, but when I found it, I also found the right uri for the service endpoint, and then looking at the source code in the SDK example, I saw I had to enter 'yes' when asked 'does it run in office 365' and then with the `michel@xyz.onmicrosoft.com` account I got access. Thanks! Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: for the connection part I suggest to use the simplified one. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929879/ms-dynamics-crm-online-2011-authentication-issues/15930366#15930366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online Instance the Webservice endpoints are located at `https://<your-subdomain-orgname>.api.crm4.dynamics.com` ... where `crm4` also may vary with the regional datacenter your instance is hosted. (crm4 is the Europe datacenter)

Apart from that you shouldn't see any issues connecting to trial organization and running the SDK samples against it.

The username for connecting is - as you already guessed - `michel@xyz.onmicrosft.com` and the address you connect to is https://xyz.api.crm4.dynamics.com

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I am connected AND inserting data, it all works!