# Creating a lead programmatically in CRM Online

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm

I have customized the lead entity in CRM for our business, is there a mechanism in CRM Online via the webservices that I can invoke to insert new records as a Lead in CRM from our local database? I cant find the correct details in Dynamics CRM Online's API. Please help!
Thanks. This is in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Simplified Connection

[MS Dynamics CRM online 2011 - Authentication issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929879/ms-dynamics-crm-online-2011-authentication-issues/15930366#15930366)

and after create the records. The metadata of the `Lead` entity is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334250(v=crm.5).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create your lead and define their attributes and save it

```
Entity lead = new Entity("lead");

// definition of lead attributes goes here
// lead.Attributes["xxxx"] = yyyy;

service.Create(lead);
```