# Push data from a web from into CRM 2015 online

Tags: webforms, record, dynamics-crm-online, createelement

I am trying to create a web from (web application) in Visual Studio 2012 to push data into CRM 2015 online. It keep saying `Metadata Contains A Reference That Cannot Be Resolved`, when the program tried to call `OrgService`.
Before that, I create a windows form to do so, it works fine. It can connect to CRM 2015 online and create a new entity record successfully. But when I move the code to Web Application. I does not work.

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ClientCredentials cre = new ClientCredentials();
    cre.UserName.UserName = "MyEmailAddress";
    cre.UserName.Password = "Password";

    Uri serviceUri = new Uri("https://QA.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

    OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, cre, null);//Error occurs here!!!!!!
    proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
    IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)proxy;
    Entity contact = new Entity("contact");

    contact["firstname"] = Convert.ToString(firstname.Text);
    contact["lastname"] = Convert.ToString(lastname.Text);
    contact["emailaddress1"] = Convert.ToString(email.Text);
    contact["mobilephone"] = Convert.ToString(phone.Text);
    proxy.Create(contact);
}
```

Error occurs at:

```
OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, cre, null);
```

Is there anyone know what is going on here? I appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide code that you use.

Comment: I just uploaded the code. Thanks.

Comment: The weird thing is that the windows form does not work now. I did not touch anything. So confused. I appreciate your helps.

Comment: you can also use the simplified connection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929879/ms-dynamics-crm-online-2011-authentication-issues/15930366#15930366

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code for initialization of service proxy:

```
IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> orgServiceManagement =
 ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(new Uri("https://democrm.api.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"));

AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();
authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _userName;
authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;
AuthenticationCredentials tokenCredentials = orgServiceManagement.Authenticate(authCredentials);

IOrganizationService organizationProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgServiceManagement, tokenCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse);
```

Comment: Hi, Andrii. We just figured it out. This is because I did not have access to send request to CRM online from the server. It needs admin access. Now we are good. The original code always works. Thank you very much. Appreciate your help.