# Access Denied Error in calling CRM 2013 Web Service

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a simple console application for test connecting to MS Dynamics CRM.
Every thing is ok with MS Dynamics CRM 2011, but Calling 2013 or upper, raise "Access is denied" error. 
My source code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 try
            {
                OrganizationServiceProxy _orgService;
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://mycrm.mylab.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

                System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials();
                clientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myuser@mylab.com", "mypsw", "mylab.com");

                OrganizationServiceProxy orgService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(uri, null, clientCredentials, null);


                QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("systemuser");
                query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "systemuserid" });
                query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();

                orgService.RetrieveMultiple(query);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
}
```

The username/paswword and security role in both CRM 2011 and 2013 are the same.
Any body can help me?

Comment: try the simplified connection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929879/ms-dynamics-crm-online-2011-authentication-issues/15930366#15930366

Comment: by editing my uri and adding my organization to it, it works. thanks: Uri("http://mycrm.mylab.com/MYORGANIZATION/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although crm service by it's uri was reachable, but accessing to Retrive method in code, by OrganizationServiceProxy  was not possible.

I add organization name to my uri address: 
Uri uri = new `Uri("http://mycrm.mylab.com/MYORGANIZATION/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");`

It works!